# How do I invoke "New Vertical Tab Group" from a VS2010 add-in?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I am building a Visual Studio 2010 add-in. One of those things I'd like to do is invoke a vertical split view of a document. I can do this in the VS GUI by selecting `Window -> New Window` followed by `Window -> New Vertical Tab Group`.

How can I invoke the same behavior from a Visual Studio add-in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ExecCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300837%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
    {
        handled = false;
        if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
        {
            if(commandName == "MyAddin1.Connect.MyAddin1")
            {
                //_applicationObject.ActiveWindow.WindowState.
                _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Window.NewWindow");
                _applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("Window.NewVerticalTabGroup");
                handled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```